# Flip function in Scheme

Tags: function, scheme

does anybody know how can I create a function in Scheme that takes no arguments and everytime I call it returns 0 or 1, depending on how many times it's been called? For example, the 1st time returns 1, the 2nd 0, the 3rd 1, etc.

I suppose I have to use a local variable inside the function, but I don't know exactly how, so that it changes value everytime I call it.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data/code/output, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Ι 've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work: (define (make-flip)
  (let ((x 1))
    (lambda ()(
               (set! x (- 1 x))
               (if (= x 0)
                         (1)
                         (0))
                       ))))

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you are calling your function.  Did you define some named function as the lambda you return with you `make-flip` function?  I guess this is "making closures 101" but it's the first time I've done to my recollection.  Anyway, I tried this way and it seemed to work:

```
(define (make-flipper)
  (let ((flip 0))
    (lambda ()  
      (set! flip (if (= flip 0) 1 0))
      flip)))

(define doit (make-flipper))

(doit)
(doit)
(doit)
```

--results in 1, then 0, then 1.  I guess you could change the value in the let if you want it to start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you're overusing parentheses, which makes your code try to call "procedures" that aren't procedures.

Your code,

```
(define (make-flip)
  (let ((x 1))
    (lambda ()
      ((set! x (- 1 x))
       (if (= x 0) (1) (0))))))
```

attempts the procedure calls `(0)` and `(1)`, and it also tries to "call" the result of the sequence

```
(set! x (- 1 x))
(if (= x 0) (1) (0)))
```

(Scheme never ignores any parentheses the way some other languages do.)

If you fix those,

```
(define (make-flip)
  (let ((x 1))
    (lambda ()
      (set! x (- 1 x))
      (if (= x 0) 1 0))))
```

it works.

The conditional isn't necessary though, you can also say

```
(define (make-flip)
  (let ((x 0))
    (lambda ()
      (set! x (- 1 x))
      x)))
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one procedure of this kind, you can also do as follows:

```
(define flip
  (let ((x 1))
    (lambda ()
      (begin0
        x
        (set! x (- 1 x))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (flip)
1
> (flip)
0
> (flip)
1
> (flip)
0
```